# Changing POP Emails To Exchange

Tags: exchange-2003, pop3

What I have is my emails going to my domain name, "DOMAIN1.com.au". I have setup a Server 2003 with Exchange 2003 on a test computer. I have created a domain on this computer, "DOMAIN2".

Could someone please explain the process, start to finish, of how to setup so that my user account on this new server can change from having pop emails going through GoDaddy to a pop account on my Outlook, to using Exchange email accounts on my local domain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Set up your Exchange environment.**

   1. In your domain2.com.au, poke holes in your firewall to allow SMTP (TCP/25 and TCP/587) and POP3 (TCP/110 and TCP/995) access.
   2. On your Exchange server, ensure your server has both Anti-virus and Anti-spam coverage of some kind.

      1. Exchange can do some anti-spam internally, but it is a poor substitute for real software designed for the purpose.
2. **Test your Exchange environment.**

   1. Set MX records for the DOMAIN2.com.au domain to point to your Exchange server.
   2. Configure Outlook to pull mail from this server.
   3. Send some test mails to [username]@domain2.com.au from your domain1.com.au account, or anywhere really, to ensure delivery works.
3. **Redirect domain1.com.au**

   1. Once you're confident that your Exchange environment works to your satisfaction, add an A record to the DNS of domain1.com.au to point to your Exchange's Public IP address.
   2. Wait a couple days for it to propagate, just to be certain.
   3. Change the MX record in domain1.com.au to point to the A-record created in the previous steps.
4. **Change your local Outlook config**

   1. For a time you will be getting mail at both locations.

      1. Keep your old godaddy POP config
      2. Set up a new Outlook mailbox setting for Exchange. You can easily run both at the same time.
5. **Clean up**

   1. Once godaddy has stopped getting any mail, you can remove that account from Outlook.

For bonus points, obtain SSL certificates for Exchange so you can use POP3 over SSL, as well as authenticated SMTP. That will allow your login credentials to be harder to grab.

Comment: Just brilliant! Thank you so much, I have been trying to find the steps of how to start and this is just perfect :)

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things you need to have in place for this.

1.) You need to have your Exchange server on the public Internet, so that it can receive mail from the outside world (Many people would consider this a dangerous thing to do, for good reason, so you definitely want a firewall between that Exchange Server and the public Internet).

2.) You need to set up MX records for your domain to point at the public IP address at which the Exchange Server can be connected to. There are numerous questions on this site explaining how to do this (plus probably some help pages on GoDaddy.com, too).

3.) Finally you need to reconfigure your Outlook client to connect to the Exchange Server.